# MongoDb MapReduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a question about mongoDb's mapReduce funcion. Say there is currently a mapReduce running that will take a long time. What will happen when a user tries to acces the same collection the mapReduce is writing to?

Does the map reduce write all the data after it is finished or does it write it while running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [concurrency](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/) page for details on mongodb locking. For your case, the map-reduce command takes a read and write lock for the relevant collections while it is running. *Portions* of the map-reduce command can be concurrent, but in the general case it is locked while running.

Comment: So if the mapReduce takes 10 minutes the collection the out function is writing to is unavailable for 10 minutes?

Comment: Unless you set non-atomic to true, see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/

Answer (score 1):

Long running read and write operations, such as queries, updates, and deletes, yield under many conditions. MongoDB operations can also yield locks between individual document modifications in write operations that affect multiple documents like update() with the multi parameter.

> In Map reduce mongoDB is doing Read and write lock, unless operations
>   are specified as non-atomic. Portions of map-reduce jobs can run
>   concurrently.